# Catching duplicate request headers with HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat6

I am running into a problem with `HttpServlet` request. I have an application in which it is to retrieve request headers. If the application finds duplicate header names, it's supposed to throw an error. However, after a bit of Googling, I found out that `HttpServletRequest` ignores duplicate header names, and proceeds with getting the first header name it encounters.  Is there anything I can do to catch those duplicate request headers?

I'm using Tomcat 6 as the application container.

This is the code:

```
int headerChecker=0;
for(Enumeration<String>names = request.getHeaderNames(); names.hasMoreElements(); ) {
    String name = (String)names.nextElement();
    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("abcd")){
        headerChecker++; // add 1 to headerChecker if abcd header is encountered
    }
    for(Enumeration<String>values = request.getHeaders(name); values.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        String value=(String)values.nextElement();
        System.out.println("name: "+name+"\tvalue: "+value);
        }
    }

    if(headerChecker! = 1){
        logger.error("abcd is duplicated, returning HTTP 404");
    } else {
        //...proceed with application
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

> ```
> name:  host   value: localhost:8080  name: user-agent value:
> CocoaRestClient/8 CFNetwork/520.4.3 Darwin/11.4.2 (x86_64)
> (MacBookPro9%2C2)  name: content-length value: 23  name: accept   value:
>
> **name: abcd  value: 1234556**  name: accept-language value: en-us  name: accept-encoding value: gzip, deflate  name: content-type    value:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded  name: connection value: keep-alive
> ```

This is the test screenshot:

[image]

Edit: Here is the servlet

```
public class HeaderServlet extends HttpServlet
{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{
    doGet(req, res);
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{
int xmsisdnChecker = 0;
String value = "";  
for(Enumeration<String> names = req.getHeaderNames();names.hasMoreElements();){
    String name = (String) names.nextElement(); 
    Enumeration<String> values = req.getHeaders(name);
    if(values != null)
    {
        while(values.hasMoreElements()) {
            if(name.equalsIgnoreCase("abcd"))
            {
                xmsisdnChecker++;
                System.out.println("ee: " + xmsisdnChecker) ;
            }

            value = (String) values.nextElement();

            System.out.println("header name: " + name + "\theader value: " + value);
        }

    }   
  }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `HttpServletRequest` doesn't *ignore* duplicate headers - it collects them.

From [`HttpServletRequest.getHeaders(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns all the values of the specified request header as an Enumeration of String objects.
>
> Some headers, such as Accept-Language can be sent by clients as several headers each with a different value rather than sending the header as a comma separated list.

So it sounds like you just need to call [`getHeaderNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaderNames()) to retrieve all of the headers that are present, then call `getHeaders(String)` with each name, and see whether the returned enumeration has more than one entry.

Comment: Thanks for the input dude, however, I have already did that in my code but still didn't caught those duplicate header names. Also, my request headers was actually a custom header name.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference that it's a custom header name - it should work fine. Please show the code you used, and say which servlet container you're using.

Comment: @user1708189: There really shouldn't be very much code - you should easily be able to edit your question to include the code. I'd actually suggest extracting it into a servlet which did *nothing else* so that you can post the complete servlet and we can try to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Aye sir. Editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your increment is in the wrong place. `HttpServletRequest` collects all the values together and presents them as multiple values of a single header. You should test and increment `headerChecker` inside the inner loop where you loop over the values. The outer loop will only encounter 'abcd' once.

Comment: I've tried placing the checker in the inner loop but still only one header was detected.

Comment: @user1708189 So then you only got one value for that header, so there was no duplicate.

Comment: i have 2 headers with same name but different values, but only one was detected and so my checker increments only once but supposed to increment twice because of the 2 header names present with same name.

Comment: @user1708189 Either that loop only printed out one value or it incremented the counter twice or it isn't coded as shown above. In the first and second cases you don't have a problem.

Comment: no Sir EJP, the counter only incremented once. Also the first code was on the actual application, the second one was a test servlet as suggested by Sir John Skeet with the headerChecker inside the inner loop as you've suggested.

Comment: By the way, I've also asked the same question here, http://www.coderanch.com/t/593920/Servlets/java/HttpServletRequest-catch-duplicate-request-header

Comment: @user1708189 So there was only one value, as you confirmed at coderanch.com. And you should not address me as 'Sir'. I am not a knight of the realm; neither I suspect is Jon Skeet.

Comment: well it's for courtesy purposes only :D

Answer (score 0):

Do an inner loop after getting the header name.

```
    Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
        Enumeration<String> headerValues = request.getHeaders(headerName);
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // This will give you multiple values on the same key.
        while (headerValues.hasMoreElements()){
            values.add(headerValues.nextElement());
        }

        headers.put(headerName, values);
    }
```